# Updating value into database

Tags: php

I have problem in updating the value into my database. The problem here is that the when i am updating the data for all rows, the data from last row will be updated into the first row. Other rows will not be updated including the last row.
Below is my code for updating...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM product where username = '$username'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));  
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$id = $rows['pro_id'];
$boxid = $rows['box_id'];
$name = $_POST['pro_name'];
$quan = $_POST['pro_quan'];
$sold = $_POST['pro_sold'];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['pro_name']); $i++) 
{
    $sql = "UPDATE product 
            SET pro_name = '" . $name[$i] . "', 
            pro_quan = " . $quan[$i] . ", 
            pro_sold = " . $sold[$i] . " 
            WHERE pro_id = " . $id . " 
            AND box_id = '" . $boxid . "' ";

    $results=mysqli_query($con, $sql);
}
```

So, i have no ideas what have gone wrong. Thanks for helping

Comment: means that if i want to update all the rows in the database using the query, the data in the last rows of the table will be updated to the first row. Which means the first row od data will be replace by the updated data of the last row

Comment: As per your requirement, I got this : "When you are updating the last record data is getting updated into the first record in the DB. Is this what you wanted to say? Is this your problem?" Clarify so that one can provide solution for the same. Your question is not so clear.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem i am facing. And the others rows data are not updated too

Comment: Previously, this code worked, but after i edited something and change it back, it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the result in a loop.
Something like that:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM product where username = '$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con)); 

    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        $id = $rows['pro_id'];
        $boxid = $rows['box_id'];
        $name = $_POST['pro_name'];
        $quan = $_POST['pro_quan'];
        $sold = $_POST['pro_sold'];
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['pro_name']); $i++)
        {
            $sql = "UPDATE product 
                SET pro_name = '" . $name[$i] . "', 
                pro_quan = " . $quan[$i] . ", 
                pro_sold = " . $sold[$i] . " 
                WHERE pro_id = " . $id . " 
                AND box_id = '" . $boxid . "' ";

            $results = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        }
    }
```

Comment: my result is located in the loop

Comment: you need to fetch rows in while loop, look at my code.